# Why does the image become bright when I set transparency in the raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Why does the image become bright when I set transparency in the raster layer in QGIS?
After setting to Nodata=0, the image becomes bright and clear. Why is that?

Comment: Please provide example images.

Answer (score 1):

By setting Nodata=0 you just changed the color gradient in the band rendering parameter.

[image]

You can adapt that contrast with the raster tool in QGIS (View -> Toolbar -> check "Raster"):
[image]